# Example HTML + JS Form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

It's my first time attempting Javascript, but after about two hours I haven't been able to figure out what mistake I'm making. I'm sure it's something small, but I haven't been able to figure out why it doesn't work in JSFiddle.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<!--Question Block One-->
Do you have a name?
<br>
Yes<input type="radio" name="first" value="yes"> 
No<input type="radio" name="first" value="no">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here's the JS:

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["first"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please answer the first question!");
  return false;
  }
 else if (x=="yes")
 {
   alert("Thanks");

 }
    else if (x=="no"
 {
  alert("Sorry, we can't help");
 }
}
```

The error:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x9b6da8c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x98e9c0c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x9b6da8c>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x9ccfe4c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

And here's the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4WesX/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket on one of your `else if` statements, see here:

```
else if (x=="no"
```

**EDIT: Actually, it's more of a problem than that.**

You're not querying the value of those radio buttons properly. First, give them IDs:

```
Yes<input type="radio" id="yes" name="first" value="yes"> 
No<input type="radio" id="no" name="first" value="no">
```

Then you can do:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var yes = document.getElementById("yes");
    var no = document.getElementById("no");

    if (!yes.checked && !no.checked)
    {
        alert("Please answer the first question!");
        return false;
    }
    else if (yes.checked)
    {
        alert("Thanks");
    }
    else if (no.checked)
    {
        alert("Sorry, we can't help");
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WesX/4/)

Comment: Oh dear. Time for bed. EDIT: Actually, it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @EGHDK It won't work in the Fiddle because JavaScript events embedded into HTML won't fire on JSFiddle.

Comment: Gotcha. Appreciate the help. Thanks again EDIT: Actually, now on a plain webpage it keeps firing off the first alert. Ideas?

Comment: @EGHDK Ah another problem, it can't get that value, can you give the radio buttons an ID?

Comment: I can do whichever, as long as I can get this simple form to function. I thought by giving a "name" it would be able to grab the value... no?

Comment: @EGHDK Check out this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4WesX/4/ I basically gave `yes` and `no` ids and I queryed the `checked` property for each one.

Comment: @EGHDK That's because I added a click event to the submit button to demonstrate (it's the first line of JS).

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much. Answered all of my questions!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30844/discussion-between-eghdk-and-mattytommo)